# ViewPagerIndicator, Fragments with heavy content, how to manage loading

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I use ViewPagerindicator with Tabs to display my content. The thing is, that my Fragments have heavy views which takes a lot of time to generate them because of many elements and pictures. I would like to display a progressbar while loading, but how to manage it? In my test instance(TestFragment) I have this method with many many textViews (it simulates the reality):

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        for (int a=0; a < 1000; a++) layout.addView(createTextView());

        return layout;
    }
```

In my pager adapter I could load all fragment once to avoid waiting for fragments while changing pages:

```
 ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
 pager.setAdapter(adapter);
 pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5);
```

but I do not know, how could I manage that all fragments where loaded? As they all are loaded each after another in the adapter:

```
  public Fragment getItem(int position) {
   return TestFragment.newInstance(position);
  }
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
 progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            progressDialog.show();

//do your stuff

progressDialog.dismiss();
```

this should just do it!

Comment: I think he mentioned that he wants to display a ProgressBar, not a progress dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Few things to note. I don't think that loading a 1000 TextViews runs the same cost as loading many "elements and pictures" as you mentioned. So, that simulation will not really give you accurate results.

Second, you mentioned that you're trying to show a progress bar while your data is loading? Is it an arbitrary amount of elements and pictures? If so, you don't want you progress bar to be there forever while the user is waiting for the content to load. IMO, a better approach is to lazy load the elements you need, with some kind of cache that prevents the underlying data from being unnecessarily reloaded.